# How to fetch time duration of an audio file from database using nodejs?

Tags: node.js

> I am new to nodejs . I create some content based on nodejs . I upload
> audio files and store it in my mongodb. But I want when I fetch data
> from mongodb ,it find the audio file time duration(how much time
> contain that audio file) and show me the file name ,image and time
> duration of that audio file. But I  have no idea about it how to find
> time duration of that file and show to user audio file ,image with
> time duration.  can any one give me a suggestion about it, and sample
> code for this type of senario.

Comment: You should save all the relevant details while inserting the document in the database, so on subsequent requests, you dont have to perform unnecesary computation.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it by using [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-audio-duration)

For Windows:

> npm install --save get-audio-duration

Usage:

```js
const { getAudioDurationInSeconds } = require('get-audio-duration')

// From a local path...
getAudioDurationInSeconds('audio.flac').then((duration) => {
  console.log(duration)
})

// From a readable stream...

const fs = require('fs')
const stream = fs.createReadStream('audio.flac')

getAudioDurationInSeconds(stream).then((duration) => {
  console.log(duration)
})
```